# How to render a layer of drawable below a button within the same cell of a table?

Tags: android, drawable, layer

I have a table in my Android app.
Each cell already consisted of an imageButton.
Is it possible to render an additional layer of drawable below each button in each cell?

This drawable's visibility will be toggled according to a particular event registered in the app (for example: counter value reaches a certain number).

Comment: Each cell in table consists of one button. You want to render a drawable below each button of each cell. Is that so? If yes please edit the answer to make it more understandable and clear.

Comment: yes you are correct. i will edit accordingly. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want put an image within a cell of table i hope below link to be useful

[XML Layout Resource with a Table Layout](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-table-layouts--mobile-4788)

If you want set a layer below of buttons check out the following address

[table layout](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/tablelayout)

Comment: hey @mehrdadib what is the second link you are about to share?

Comment: i want to be able to change the attribute of the drawable (which is to be placed below a table) programmatically